# How to get the height of the entered text in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Is there a possible way to get the height of an entered text in a `JTextPane`?
Pixels would be great but any value that can represent it would do.
For example I have entered in the `JTextPane` this:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
>   five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
>   the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
>   more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
>   including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Is there a way to get a value for how long it is(not how many lines it is)?
I need this because if I enter a picture in one of the lines, the total height changes and I want to be able to know how much it changes exactly. The `JTextPane`, I use has a `StyledDocument` and doesn't have html. I made an `SSCCE` but instead of an image I used two different font sizes to show the difference between the height of the 2 `JTextPanes`.

```
public class Fonts extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Fonts frame = new Fonts();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Fonts() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        textPane.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        JTextPane textPane_1 = new JTextPane();
        textPane_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        textPane_1.setEditable(false);

        StyledDocument doc1 = textPane_1.getStyledDocument();
        String s = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." +
                " Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown" +
                " printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not" +
                " only five centuries, but also the ";
        try {
            doc.insertString(0, s, null);
            doc1.insertString(0, s, null);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(textPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(textPane_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 208, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(textPane_1, Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(textPane, Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 251, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }
}
```

So is there a way to get the height of the 2 JTextPanes?

Comment: *"The JTextPane has a StyledDocument and doesn't have html."*  `JTextPane` does support HTML.

Comment: yes is possible, both height and weight too, for bettter help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JTextPane` and with text inserted in your question, otherwise look at `swing.TextUtilities`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the approach described [here](http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html) to measure the JEditorPane/JTextPane's height of content for fixed width.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This helped me resolve a problem that I had been working on for 2 weeks now. I'm incredibly grateful!

Comment: Server of the linked URL isn't accessible. Content can be found on the [wayback-machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220518052434/http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html). It's the same answer as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902627/406423