# How to set preferred size of JTextPane to its content size?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, preferredsize

I have a JPanel with Boxlayout and some JTextPanes and JPanels that will be added to it dynamically. I want to set the preferred size of the JTextPanes to fit their content. I use StyledDocument for my JTextPane. How can I do this?

Edit:
When I create a new JTextPane I have its content and it won't change. Here is my code:

```
public void display(final String text){
    StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
    final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
    Style defaultStyle = sc.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
    final Style style = sc.addStyle("MainStyle", defaultStyle);
    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(){
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
            return new Dimension(text.length()*5, getContentHeight(text.length()*5,text));
        }
        @Override 
        public Dimension  getMaximumSize(){
            return  new Dimension(430, getContentHeight(text.length()*5,text));
        }
    };
    receive.setStyledDocument(doc);
    receive.setEditable(false);
    receive.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(text.length()*5, getContentHeight(text.length()*5,text)));
    
    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),text,style);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Jpanel.add(pane);
    
}

public int getContentHeight(int i, String content) {
        JEditorPane dummyEditorPane=new JEditorPane();
        dummyEditorPane.setSize(i,Short.MAX_VALUE);
        dummyEditorPane.setText(content);
        return dummyEditorPane.getPreferredSize().height;
    }
```

The issue is in the `getMinimumSize()`, `getMaximumSize()`, and `setPreferredSize()` methods! Also in the width that I set for `dummyEditorPane.setSize(i,Short.MAX_VALUE);` How can I set a fixed size for the JTextPane?

Comment: It's better to share the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix size of JTextPane to its content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181929/how-to-fix-size-of-jtextpane-to-its-content)

Answer (score 2):

Add `JTextPane` inside [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) to fit as per its content. If it doesn't work then override `getPreferredSize()` to set the preferred size if needed.

```
 @Override
 public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
     return new Dimension(..., ...);
 }
```

See *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for examples.

Comment: My problem is to set proper dimension. How can I find the suitable width and height?

Comment: I want a way for java not javascript.

Comment: Have you written any code in java? please share if you need help that gives a point to find out the issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html) is a tip how to measure height for fixed width

```
public static int getContentHeight(String content) {
    JEditorPane dummyEditorPane=new JEditorPane();
    dummyEditorPane.setSize(100,Short.MAX_VALUE);
    dummyEditorPane.setText(content);

    return dummyEditorPane.getPreferredSize().height;
}

int h=getContentHeight("Long text to be measured in the JEditorPane");
```

Comment: I am using jtextpane which have style, how can I set my style to JEditorPane so that it getContentHeight correctly ?