# How to fix size of JTextPane to its content?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have `JPanel` with `BoxLayout`.

```
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS){
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target){
            return new Dimension(100, 25);
        }
        @Override
        public Dimension maximumLayoutSize(Container target){
            return new Dimension(100,25);
        }

});
```

I add some `JTextPane` and `JPanel` to it dynamically.
I call the method below to add new `JTextPane` to my jpanel and pass the text to it.

```
public void display(final String text){
    StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
    final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
    Style defaultStyle = sc.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
    final Style style = sc.addStyle("MainStyle", defaultStyle);
    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(){
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override // how should I write this:
        public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
            return new Dimension(text.length()*5, getContentHeight(text.length()*5,text));
        }
        @Override // how should I write this:
        public Dimension  getMaximumSize(){
            return  new Dimension(430, getContentHeight(text.length()*5,text));
        }
    };
    receive.setStyledDocument(doc);
    receive.setEditable(false);
    // how should I write this: 
    receive.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(text.length()*5, getContentHeight(text.length()*5,text)));

    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),text,style);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    panel.add(pane);

}
```

so the content won't change.

```
public int getContentHeight(int i, String content) {
        JEditorPane dummyEditorPane=new JEditorPane();
        dummyEditorPane.setSize(i,Short.MAX_VALUE);
        dummyEditorPane.setText(content);
        return dummyEditorPane.getPreferredSize().height;
}
```

The issue is in `getMinimumSize()` and `getMaximumSize()` and `setPreferredSize()` method! 
Also in width that I set for `dummyEditorPane.setSize(i,Short.MAX_VALUE);`
So How can I set this method to fix size for textpane?

Comment: getMinimumSize() and getMaximumSize() and setPreferredSize() method! -is about how (concrete LayoutManager) to accept those sizing hints

Comment: how can I set these so that LayoutManeger accept the size, I want to set these so that jtextpane fix to its content

Comment: or maybe I should change the  `minimumLayoutSize(Container target)` and `minimumLayoutSize(Container target)`.

Comment: can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can test? Also a screenshot if possible? (Post link and we edit it since you don't have enough rep yet). Also... if I'm not wrong the `getMaximumSize()` and `getMinimumSize()` should be outside the void. Try it and tell me if worked, else consider the part about MCVE :) I'll be glad to try to help you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use `setPreferredSize` but maybe you might benefit from the normal usage of a JScrollPane:

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(pane));
```

The JTextPane will adapt to its document size, and the JScrollPane takes further care of scrollbars when needed.

Comment: I want jtextpane with fixed size, my panel already has scrollbar for scrolling its content.

Comment: How can I `setPreferredSize` correctly to fix to the content

Comment: Okay, then my answer is no solution.

Comment: I want each of my line be 440px or smaller if the text length is small(so the height should fix for one line and I should estimate width), but I don't know how can I measure the length of text

Answer (score 0):

`getPreferredSize()` already returns the size of the content. So the solution is just to not use `setPreferredSize`, but use

```
jtp.setSize(jtp.getWidth(),jtp.getPreferredSize().height);//For fixed width
```

or

```
jtp.setSize(jtp.getPreferredSize());//for unlimited width and no wrapping
```

This will set the height of the JTextPane to match its content.

To do this with a BoxLayout, you might want to

- extends your JTextPane and override `getMinimumSize` and `getMaximumSize` to make them return `getPreferredSize`:

  ```
          final JTextPane myJTP = new JTextPane() {

              @Override
              public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                  return getPreferredSize();
              }

              @Override
              public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                  return getPreferredSize();
              }

          };
  ```
- or extends BoxLayout to make the `layoutContainer` method set the correct size to its children.