# How to get the height of entered text in a JTextArea while it is being entered by the user?

Tags: java, swing

I realise this may sound like a duplicate of [How to get the height of the entered text in a JTextPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040586/how-to-get-the-height-of-the-entered-text-in-a-jtextpane) but it is not.

I am trying to determine the preferred height of a `JTextArea` while the user is typing into the box. To do so, following advice found elsewhere, I am using the following code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        text.setColumns(10);

        text.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                new DocumentListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent inDocumentEvent) {
                        System.out.println("new preferred: " + text.getPreferredSize());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent inDocumentEvent) {
                        System.out.println("new preferred: " + text.getPreferredSize());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent inDocumentEvent) {

                    }
                }
        );

        frame.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This mostly works *but not quite*. The problem is that when the user enters enough characters to cause the line to wrap, the preferred size does not seem to be updated until the *next character entry*.

To reproduce:

- Run the above program
- Enter characters until the caret is just next to the right edge, so that the next keypress will cause the line to wrap
- Press another character.
- At this point, the line will wrap, and the height of the printed PreferredSize should be greater than previously since there are two rows in the `JTextArea`, but it is not.
- Press another character. *Now* the PreferredSize updates to reflect the fact that there are two rows.
- The same thing happens when deleting characters.

Is this a bug? What's going on here?

Comment: *"How to get the height of entered text in a JTextArea"* ***Why*** (do that rather than set the row count & put the text area in a scroll pane)?

Comment: The JTextArea is used as part of a graphical application where it is used as a text box floating on top of another display. When the user creates the "text box", it should expand as the user types text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with a simple trick, called `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Simply change the line:

```
System.out.println("new preferred: " + text.getPreferredSize());
```

by the line

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> System.out.println("new preferred: " + text.getPreferredSize()));
```

And it works! Probably the TextArea provide size update after the key event was processed.

Comment: Of course! Now why didn't I think of that? :D Thanks